# Is it a good practice to use a name for a company if that name already occurs in a couple of other domain names?

Tags: planning, estimation, product-owner, business-case, product-manager

Not sure if this is a proper community to post this question, if not, please recommend me one.

I had a name in my mind (let's call it `<the_name_i_like>`) for my website and company, so I registered a domain name as:

`<the_name_i_like><actual_service>.com`

In search results for `the_name_i_like`, I have found 3-4 domain names having it as a part, and with a different `<actual_service>`. For example:
`<the_name_i_like>consulting.com`
`<the_name_i_like>realestate.com`
etc. (all US-based, by the way)

The domain `<the_name_i_like>.com` has been taken already, although there's no website under it, the browser just keeps rotating if I try to load it.

My question is, shall I keep using `<the_name_i_like><actual_service>.com` or is it better to register another name?

What about registering a company with a different name `<another_name_that_i_like>` and creating a website under `<the_name_i_like><actual_service>.com` as one of services that my company provides?

Comment: It is not the correct community for sure, but I don't know which community it should go to...

Comment: @NezihTINAS: depending on the actual reason for asking, it might be OK to be here or on Economics.SE (entrepreneurial management, differentiation) or it might be suitable on Law.SE (for legal aspects).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about how it goes from a legal standpoint.

But from a business standpoint, why would you want your customers to confuse you with other businesses? How many established famous businesses do you know, which share a name?

Ultimately (or primarily?) the name of the business is the beginning of your differentiation on the market. If you cannot differentiate your name properly, then you probably end up becoming some kind of *Mike* or *Adibas* or even *SUMSANG*.

---

If you are unlucky, you might find yourself in a kind of [**Mike Rowe Soft**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_v._MikeRoweSoft) situation - with the difference that you are probably not a 12-year old, leading in return to a much mode unpleasant outcome.